# cant access a file path from xamarin forms project

Tags: forms, xamarin, path, sendmail

I have a recording play, stop , playback and send email functionality that was develop in xamarin  (PCL) and  it is called from the portable using Depency services . the problem is the attachment is not found,I am 100 % that exist and it is save in the phone. when I track the path in the phone is "/storage/emulated/0/TEST5.mp4" this is obtained on the droid part 
and on  the pcl  , I am doing this

button send .....

```
var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()
                   .To("anyemaim@lol")
                     .Cc("anyemaim@lol")
                    .Subject(" test MP4" )
                   .Body("")
                    .WithAttachment("<TEST5.mp4>", "image/jpeg")
                    .Build();
```

, but it is not finding this path , I also tried /storage/emulated/0/TEST5.mp4.
Thank you !

Comment: are you sure it's "image/jpeg" ?

Comment: no, actually I am not trying to add any image just the path (TEST5) , it seems that attachment needs 2 strings , not sure why ,  put it there just for testing only . Thank you for reply

Comment: try to use absolute path like "file:///storage/emulated/0/TEST5.mp4"

Comment: @Taier . Thanks a lot , I will try this and let you know shortly

Comment: @Taier , sorry for the late response , I did try that , but still nothing .Technically , it is possible to access to an android file calling it from Forms?

Comment: I'm not sure if that possible directly from forms, but you totally could do it if you provide a native implementation https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/accessing-native-features-with-xamarinforms--cms-22103